# Why i get error at the end of the function?

Tags: c

I work on my C tutorial.

I have this function:

```
void sortString(char c[][5], int size) {
    char temp[] = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(c[j],c[j+1]) > 0) //arr + j
            {
                strcpy(temp, c[j]);// only strcpy, assignment not works
                strcpy(c[j], c[j + 1]);
                strcpy(c[j + 1], temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after the outer loop ends and when function ends I get this error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'temp' was corrupted.
```

Any idea why I get error above?

Comment: `char temp[] = "";` is too small to copy into. Please try `char temp[5] = "";`

Comment: `temp` has size 1, which is enough to store the empty string and nothing else.

Comment: Since you don’t specify it explicitly, the size of `temp` is taken from the size of the initializer, which is 1.  Therefore, `temp` isn’t large enough to hold any of your strings.  Either use `temp[] = “    “;` or `temp[5] = “”:`

Comment: @JohnBode I recommend `"` instead of `“` or `”`. :-)

Comment: @JohnBode, but why I get the error when function ends?it  works fine while it runs in loops inner and outer.

Comment: @Michael You're lucky you're getting an error at all. Bugs in C code can manifest in all kinds of weird and wonderful ways.

Comment: Welcome to the Wonderful World of Undefined Behaviour! ;-) It may crash, or not, or only now, or only with full moon, or when your girl friend just left you, or at your grandma's 16th birthday or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definition of temp[] initialises it with one char (byte) 0. When you copy c[j], you copy all the bytes of c[j] to the memory, started from temp. If c[j] has more than 1 char, extra memory not belonging to temp will be overwritten and likely it is a local stack frame of the function.

Compiler checks this in debug mode and reports - see details in [Run-Time Error Checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks), and [Stack Allocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew5tede7.aspx).

And if you allocate too much on the stack you'll get stack overflow!

Comment: "*Compiler checks this in debug mode*" "debug mode? Which debug mode? In C never rely on the compiler doing the programmer's work.

Comment: /RTC switch - which is enabled in debug mode by default. Debug and release generate different code. If you write direct range checks for a vector or specify the compiler to do this - these both helps.

Answer (score 1):

Few observation from the code you mentioned. 
Firstly, here

`char temp[] = "";`

`temp` size is too small to hold `c[j]`. Make it bigger enough so that it can hold `c[j]`. For e.g

`char temp[5] = "";`

Secondaly, bubble sort inner `for` loop iteration is not correct. Instead of `j < size - 1` use `j < size - i-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough buffer store as temp variable. You will need to know max_length for the given strings and allocate enough memory on stack. If you don't know this, then the other option is dynamic allocation on heap.

Comment: `memset` is pointless. `temp` is always set before it's used. The maximum length is known (`char c[][5]`).

Comment: max_length for the strings? How?

Comment: I corrected my response based on your comment. You are right that memset() is pointless in this case.